# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org.schema/context/spring- context-4.2.3.xsd'

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm writing a spring MVC project. I have the following context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org.schema/context/spring-context-4.2.3.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

This xml has a mistake. The error message is :

```
 Multiple annotations found at this line:
   - schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document     'http://www.springframework.org.schema/context/spring-
 context-4.2.3.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the 
 document is not <xsd:schema>.
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
 'context:component-scan'.
```

jar versions are

```
spring-webmvc-4.2.3
spring-context-4.2.3
spring-core-4.2.3
spring-web-4.2.3
spring-beans-4.2.3
spring-aop-4.2.3
spring-expression-4.2.3
```

Could somebody help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `http://www.springframework.org.schema/context/spring-context-4.2.3.xsd` file so your XML file in incorrect.

The correct path is [`http://www.springframework.org.schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/resources/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.2.xsd).

As a general rule of thumb, Spring XSD are released for every [minor release](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-build-gradle/wiki/Spring-project-versioning), not for every micro release.